# Selenium build error

Tags: java, selenium

I need to compile Selenium project on my own.
The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver) tells that one just has to execute `./go` on the root directory.

Yet, that does not work. It tells me that `: No such file or directory`.

All needed tools are installed.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you in the right directory? Is there a `go` file in that directory?

Comment: So what have you tried to overcome this?

Comment: To confirm.. are you on linux or windows? Are you in the correct directory having the code source?

Comment: @EricBouwers: Yes, I am in the root folder of Selenium's Git containing the ``go`` file.

@SiKing: Tried all hints the documentation describes. Could not find helpful information on the net.

@Purus: On Linux. See first answer.